# IntelliJ - Why does the target folder is created with an padlock?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, testng

I hope you guys can help me with this, after running testng, the target folder is created with a padlock

[image: target folder image]

and due this I can't run `mvn clean test` cause this folder can't be removed by maven

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project TestCases: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /Users/administrator/qa-automation/01LoginProject/TestCases/target/surefire-reports/testng.css -> [Help 1]
```

How can I prevent the target from being created without the padlock?

Comment: [Padlock](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html#common-icons) on a project folder means it contains a read-only class, for example from a jar of an external library.

Comment: Hello Koyasha, that reference helped me to understand many things. Thanks for the response

Comment: You are welcome Horacio. Let me post it as an answer then for better visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Padlock on a project folder means it contains a read-only class.

[image]

See [this article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html#common-icons) for more information on file types and icon references in IntelliJ IDEA.